# How to stop writing to a capture file using tcpdump after it reaches a specific size

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, tcpdump

I am looking for some solution to stop capturing the tcpdump packet after it capture a specified size .I am using the below command to achieve this but it looks like the tcpdump is not writing all the captured packet to the specified file(myfile.pcap).

sudo tcpdump -i en0  -C 10 -W 1 -z ./stop-tcpdump.sh -w myfile.pcap  -K -n

```
cat stop-tcpdump.sh 
#!/bin/sh
TCP_EXECUTABLE="tcpdump"
pid=$(pidof ${TCP_EXECUTABLE})
sudo kill -2 $pid
```

Comment: If you are limiting the filesize, it's expected behavior for some of the packets to be dropped that would increase the filesize past the threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution for `tcpdump` is probably just to increase `-W 1` to `-W 2`.  This will cause a 2nd capture file to begin to be written, but the 1st file of 10MB will remain fully intact instead of getting truncated, because the `tcpdump` instance won't necessarily be killed due to timing issues before that happens.

Alternatively, you could switch to using [`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html) or [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), both of which support an explicit `-a filesize:value` option, so no post-rotate kill script is needed.  Note that unlike `tcpdump`'s `-C` option, this option expects the value in units of kB, not MB.